# How to free dynamically allocated memory in c in visual studio 2005

Tags: c, memory, dynamic, free

How to free dynamically allocated memory in c in visual studio 2005?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an alternative way to free dynamically allocated memory in C - not using the free() function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750060/is-there-an-alternative-way-to-free-dynamically-allocated-memory-in-c-not-using)

Answer (score 2):

`malloc` and `free`.

```
// Allocate the memory
int* a = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);

// Free the memory.
free(a);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `malloc` + `free` or `LocalAlloc` + `LocalFree` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use **malloc** and **free**
or if you want to use the windows APIs then use
**HeapAlloc** and **HeapFree**.

Examples:

case 1:

```
// allocate
char *buf = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);

// free
free(buf);
```

case 2:

```
// allocate
char *buf = HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, sizeof(char) * 100); // the allocated memory is initialized to zero

// free
HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, buf);
```